# Error when trying to change the color of background and the absolute position of elements in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

I'm trying to create a `JButton` (`r`) and to set its absolute position. I also want to change the background color. When I insert a new `FlowLayout` like this: `setLayout(new FlowLayout());` the color of the background doesn't change while the absolute position does.

Meanwhile when removing this: `setLayout(new FlowLayout());` the absolute position doesn't change while the color does. So can anyone explain me why this happens and how can I change the code in a way thet both of them the color and the posiotion absolute of the `JButton` change?

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Back extends JFrame{

    private JButton r;
    private JButton c;
    private Container container;
    public Back(){
        super("title");
        //setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        ran = new Random();
        value = nextValue();

        r=new JButton("ROLL");
        add(r,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        thehandler hand=new thehandler(this);//konstruktori i handler merr nje instance te Background
        r.addActionListener(hand);
    }

    private class thehandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Back  d = new Back() ;

         d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         d.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
         d.setSize(700,500);

         d.setVisible(true);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Back extends JFrame{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JButton r;
public Back(){
    super("title");
    setLayout(null);
    r=new JButton("ROLL");
    r.setBounds(20, 20, 70, 30);
    add(r);

    Thehandler hand=new Thehandler(this);//konstruktori i handler merr nje instance te Background
    r.addActionListener(hand);
}

private class Thehandler implements ActionListener{
    private JFrame frame;
    public Thehandler(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Random ra = new Random();
        int r = ra.nextInt(255);
        int g = ra.nextInt(255);
        int b = ra.nextInt(255);
        Color c = new Color(r, g, b);

        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(c);

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     Back  d = new Back() ;

     d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     d.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
     d.setSize(700,500);

     d.setVisible(true);    
}
}
```

Comment: Right answer!Thanks a lot!The right way to set absolute position of elements!

Comment: *"The right way to set absolute position of elements!"* The right way to make a fragile GUI that will fall apart on the next OS or PLAF. Don't to this in your apps., programmers.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code, so that it would compile:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Back extends JFrame {

    private JButton r;
    private Random ran;
    private String position = BorderLayout.NORTH;
    private Container container;

    public Back() {
        super("title");
        ran = new Random();
        int value = ran.nextInt();

        r = new JButton("ROLL");
        thehandler hand = new thehandler(this);//konstruktori i handler merr     nje instance te Background
        r.addActionListener(hand);

        this.change();

    }

    private class thehandler implements ActionListener {
        private final Back back;

        public thehandler(Back back) {
            this.back = back;
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            back.change();
        }
    }

    private void change() {
        this.remove(r);
        String newPos = null;
        if (position.equals(BorderLayout.NORTH))
            newPos = BorderLayout.SOUTH;
        else 
            newPos = BorderLayout.NORTH;
        this.add(r, newPos);
        this.position = newPos;
        int r = ran.nextInt(255);
        int g = ran.nextInt(255);
        int b = ran.nextInt(255);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(r, g, b));
        this.revalidate();
        this.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Back d = new Back();

        d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        d.setSize(700, 500);
        d.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The layout will arrange the JComponents in your program: thus commenting or uncommenting the line "setLayout(new FlowLayout());" will move the button. There are different Layouts, like FLowLayout, BorderLayout or GridLayout. I would strongly recommend you to use Layouts instead of absolute positioning!

I cannot reproduce your problem that removing that line will change the color. Instead I believe the color is changed at the line "d.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);" if you want a differnt color, you can set a different one here!

Comment: Ok the code compiles but doesn't solve my ploblem! The button is still in the north of the page eventhough the absolute pos is South

Comment: I edit the code so that it solves what I belive your intention is. Note that this solution does not need to change the layout, rather the psoition of the component in the layout. I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I know this might not be the answer you are looking for. But take it as recommendation. If you want the absolute position you need to change the layout to

```
setLayout(null);
```

I would recommend you to use GridBagLayout:
[Oralce's documentation GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

and the youtube video that helped me a lot :
[GridBagLayout tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2vDARb7gx8)